# Threaded CSS li

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to solve one of my dilemmas, which is grouping messages ex:

```js
$("li").each(function() {
  $(this).addClass("thread");
});
```

```css
.him {
  background-color: rgba(240, 255, 183, 1);
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px 0 #d0d0d0;
  padding: 10px;
}
.me {
  background-color: rgba(123, 245, 23, 1);
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px 0 #d0d0d0;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="him">hello</li>
  <li class="me">hello</li>
  <li class="me">how are you?</li>
  <li class="me">please answer!!</li>
  <li class="him">sorry was away</li>
  <li class="him">hello</li>
  <li class="me">hello</li>
  <li class="me">how are you?</li>
  <li class="him">hello</li>
  <li class="me">hello</li>
  <li class="me">how are you?</li>
  <li class="me">please answer!!</li>
  <li class="him">sorry was away</li>
</ul>
```

I would like that if for example class me have more li it become a thread so that first one will have only top round corners insides will have none and last will have bottom round corners for both class .me and .him

I tried a lot by myself and couldn't figure out how to do it, even with jquery as I could get the thread class but on each one.

I would like this result

```css
.me1 {

  background-color: rgba(123, 245, 23, 1);

  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;

  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px 0 #d0d0d0;

  padding: 10px;

}

.me2 {

  background-color: rgba(123, 245, 23, 1);

  border-radius: 0;

  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px 0 #d0d0d0;

  padding: 10px;

}

.me3 {

  background-color: rgba(123, 245, 23, 1);

  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;

  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px 0 #d0d0d0;

  padding: 10px;

}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="me1">hello</li>
  <li class="me2">how are you?</li>
  <li class="me3">please answer!!</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: unclear what you're saying....

Comment: updated to be more clear

Comment: Isn't `$('li').addClass('thread');` shorter?

Comment: but i want that for example every .me class group has thread on them if they are more then one

<li class="me">hello</li>
  <li class="me">how are you?</li>
  <li class="me">please answer!!</li>

if only one keep my first format

Comment: The javascript is unnecessary.  You can just give the containing element a class, instead of giving all of the child elements a class.  eg. `<ul class="thread">`. But a list isn't necessarily the best idea for this. The structure of a conversation is not a "list", It is also not "unordered" - it has an ordered structure. So I'd use a `div` and `p` tags instead.  As for your question, you may have an easier time if you separate out your combined CSS rules - for example, instead of `border-radius` try `border-bottom-left-radius`, `border-bottom-right-radius` and etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see what you are trying to do.

You would need to only slightly change your html yo get this to work.

You will need to use data attr and classes.

http://jsfiddle.net/pn3hefrh/

```
<ul>
  <li data-user="him" class="him">hello</li>
  <li data-user="me"  class="me">hello</li>
  <li data-user="me"  class="me">how are you?</li>
  <li data-user="me"  class="me">please answer!!</li>
  <li data-user="him"  class="him">sorry was away</li>
  <li data-user="him"  class="him">hello</li>
  <li data-user="me"  class="me">hello</li>
  <li data-user="me"  class="me">how are you?</li>
  <li data-user="him"  class="him">hello</li>
  <li data-user="me"  class="me">hello</li>
  <li data-user="me"  class="me">how are you?</li>
  <li data-user="me"  class="me">please answer!!</li>
  <li data-user="him" class="him">sorry was away</li>
</ul>


.him {
  background-color: rgba(240, 255, 183, 1);
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px 0 #d0d0d0;
  padding: 10px;
}
.me {
  background-color: rgba(123, 245, 23, 1);
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px 0 #d0d0d0;
  padding: 10px;
}

.middle {
  border-radius: 0;
}

.top {
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
}

.bottom {
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px ;
}
```

This JS could be optimized but here is a rough of how to get it to work

```
$("li").each(function() {
   var user = $(this).attr("data-user");
   var next = $(this).next().attr("data-user");
   var prev = $(this).prev().attr("data-user");
   if ( user != prev){
     $(this).addClass('top');   
   }
   if(user == next && user == prev) {
    $(this).addClass('middle');
   }
   if(user == prev && user != next){
     $(this).addClass('bottom');   
   }
   if(user != prev && user != next){
     $(this).addClass('bottom');  
     $(this).addClass('top'); 
   }
```

});

Comment: You are amazing, exactly how i needed it :) but fixed your last <code>if(user != prev && user != next){
         $(this).removeClass('top'); 
    }</code> thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can use some CSS styling.

Just targeting the immediate sibling selector, you can give a different look to second occurences of *me* or *him*

The top corners are easy.

The bottom corners of the previous element are harder, I have solved with a little margin trick.

```js
$("li").each(function() {
  $(this).addClass("thread");
});
```

```css
.him {
  background-color: rgba(240, 255, 183, 1);
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px 0 #d0d0d0;
  padding: 10px;
}
.me {
  background-color: rgba(123, 245, 23, 1);
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px 0 #d0d0d0;
  padding: 10px;
}
.me + .me {
  border-top-left-radius: 0px;
  border-top-right-radius: 0px;  
  margin-top: -10px;
  padding-top: 20px; 
}
.him + .him {
  border-top-left-radius: 0px;
  border-top-right-radius: 0px;    
  margin-top: -10px;
  padding-top: 20px; 
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="him">hello</li>
  <li class="me">hello</li>
  <li class="me">how are you?</li>
  <li class="me">please answer!!</li>
  <li class="him">sorry was away</li>
  <li class="him">hello</li>
  <li class="me">hello</li>
  <li class="me">how are you?</li>
  <li class="him">hello</li>
  <li class="me">hello</li>
  <li class="me">how are you?</li>
  <li class="me">please answer!!</li>
  <li class="him">sorry was away</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, the structure of this is not ideal. I'd try something like this:

```
    <div class="transcript">
    <ul class="instance person-1">
        <li>hello</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="instance person-2">
        <li>hello</li>
        <li>how are you?</li>
        <li>please answer!!</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="instance person-1">
        <li>sorry was away</li>
        <li>hello</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="instance person-2">
        <li>hello</li>
        <li>how are you?</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="instance person-1">
        <li>hello</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="instance person-2">
        <li>hello</li>
        <li>how are you?</li>
        <li>please answer!!</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="instance person-1">
        <li class="him">sorry was away</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This way is also more future-proof, if at a later date you want to alter the design of the chat transcript you've got a more modular layout to work with, you could even have group chats.

Plus now all you have to do is loop through each 'instance' and determine what number is on the end of 'person' to assign the appropriate colour. You wouldn't even need javascript for this as CSS can handle that without a problem.

Comment: but would want to push data every few seconds so if i posted
hello and after i posted how are you? how can i know which ul it goes too. I am trying to make a chat box with threaded messages

Comment: Well presumably you already have a script to change the class depending on who is talking. Instead just alter this script to create a new instance of '.instance'. If a new instance hasn't been created then it just keeps pushing data to the current one.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your HTML to something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li class="him">hello</li>
    <li class="me">
        <ul class="me_ul">
            <li>hello</li>
            <li>hello</li>
            <li>hello</li>
            <li>hello</li>
            <li>hello</li>
            <li>how are you?</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="him">
        <ul class="him_ul">
            <li>hello</li>
            <li>how are you?</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="me">hello</li>
    <li class="him">hello</li>
    <li class="me">hello</li>
    <li class="him">hello</li>
</ul>
```

Then apply your CSS to the `UL` elements, like this:

```
li {
    list-style-type:none
}
.him, .me {
    background-color: rgba(240, 255, 183, 1);
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px 0 #d0d0d0;
    padding: 10px;
}
.me_ul, .him_ul {
    background-color: rgba(123, 245, 23, 1);
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.me_ul li, .him_ul li {
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

This is not only easier, but semantically correct, think you only have to people, so they're represented by a `li`, now, every piece of talk they do is a part of the same user, hence you need to next their comments inside this `ul` so you can separate one people's comments from the other

[See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g6jk99z6/)

Comment: But a comment thread is not an unordered list.  It's ordered, and thinking of it as a list is kind of strange.  They're paragraphs or quotes...

Comment: I'm re-using the OP code. Also, every single CMS I know displays comments as lists, so guess several million sites using that approach is the exact opposite of "strange", more likely the standard

Comment: Yes, you are re-using the OP code but you're also altering it to what you think is "semantically correct".  It doesn't appear to actually be. I don't know what CMSes use, but just because they do it, doesn't mean it's the best way.